# How to access a table data element based on the value of another table data element in a Cypress test

Tags: cypress

In the below HTML table, I am trying to find a row based on the user's name (i.e. `John`), & then click the `Menu` button associated with that `tr` record:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a ng-click="onViewItemDetails(item, null, $event)">John</a></td>
        <td><a>Smith</a></td>
        <td><a><i class="activity-burger-menu">Menu</i></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In pseudo-code it should be something like:

```
cy.getRecordBasedOnName('John).then(() => {
    // After finding that record, click the button with this class, on that row
    cy.get('.activity-burger-menu').click()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution that uses `siblings`

```
cy.contains('td', 'John')
  .siblings().eq(10)
    .click();
```

Comment: Just a caution in case if the position of the element is changed or any element is removed `eq(10)` will cause failures.

Answer (score 1):

To find a row with a specific text, you'll want to use [`.contains(selector, text)`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Selector) to find the row then search within the row for the menu text to click.

NOTE:`.contains()` will only return the first matching DOM element so if you have multiple matching names you may want to use a different approach.

```js
// depending on your how your text is parsed you may
// need to reconfigure the text used in .contains()
cy.contains('tr', /John Smith/i)
  // use .contains() again to find the menu within returned row
  .contains('td', /Menu/i)
  // always good to add assertions
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `within` and `parent` for this:

```js
cy.contains('td', 'John')
  .parent() //parent gets the tr element
  .within(() => {
    //within scopes the next commands inside the tr
    cy.get('.activity-burger-menu').click()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `siblings()` solution, you can specify a selector inside the `siblings()` command

```js
cy.contains('td', 'John')
  .siblings(':contains(Menu)') 
  .click()
```